# Changed database context to 'MyDbName'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, error-handling

I am catching all errors on my Sql Server, I got errors:

> Changed database context to 'MyDbName'. 
>   Changed language setting to us_english.

I haven't found any clear explanation of problem and severity of this error. Is it critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an informational message for SQL Server stating successful connection. It is one of three that it will usually return. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx).

Comment: Why is this an "error" message? * I know this is an old post. just would like to know.